# Getting Selenium firefox driver to quit properly - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running a test over and over. Each time I run I see that another firefox appears as seen here:

[image: multiple firefox session]

Where can I add the driver.quit() (or similar) function so it properly cleans itself up on program close?

I am only calling driver with this:

```
me.Drivers.Test = new FirefoxDriver();
me.Drivers.Test.get(websiteLink);
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the test annotation and call `me.Drivers.Test.quit()` in `@After` (In JUnit its `@After`, every testing environment has its own naming convention).

Example:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    me.Drivers.Test = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Test
public void test() {
    me.Drivers.Test.get(websiteLink);
}

@After
public void after() {
    me.Drivers.Test.quit();
}
```

The `@Before` annotation will run before the test starts, some kind of test setup.

In `@Test` you are doing the actual testing.

And `@After` will run after the test is finished, and there you are doing all the cleaning.

For more details you can look [here](http://java2novice.com/junit-examples/junit-annotations/).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `me.Drivers.Test` is an instance of WebDriver. So you can use `me.Drivers.Test.quit()` at the end of your script to quit the webdriver.

Comment: Yes it is an instance of the WebDriver. Unfortunately the WebDriver will continue until abruptly stopped (Browser closed)

Comment: Could you explain what is your expectation? Do you want to close the browser immediately after `me.Drivers.Test.get(websiteLink);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Like you initialize the driver you have to quit it.
Use:

```
me.Drivers.Test.quit()
```